# Sonarqube 5.2 starts, but not accessible

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

Sonarqube 5.2 starts without errors, but is not accessible. It was working fine until a couple of days ago.
1. Sonar is configured to  run on Port 9000, but the port is free.
2. Firefox cannot access the url.

This is the sonar.log entry:

```
*--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
2018.04.11 22:44:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/scratch/aime/Sonar/sonarqube-5.2/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:*./lib/search/* *org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process3042361883049663302properties
2018.04.11 22:44:47 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2018.04.11 22:44:47 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2018.04.11 22:44:48 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1523511887257] version[1.7.2], pid[1648], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
2018.04.11 22:44:48 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1523511887257] initializing ...
2018.04.11 22:44:48 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1523511887257] loaded [], sites []*
```

There has been no change in the sonar.properties and sonar was fine until a few days ago.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Maybe some pending updates? Server restart didn't work?

Comment: v5.2 is very old, it will be hard to get help on it. For now I suggest you check logs in _sonar.log_ , and ultimately upgrade to more recent version.

Comment: @Peska Restart did not work. I left it at that.

Comment: Like @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam advised, I am going to try it with the latest Sonarqube.

Comment: @g-ann-sonarsource-team Thanks for formatting.